# Socket.io falling back to XHR polling

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a Express, Node and Socket.io application, when I inspect Network, I can see Socket is falling back to XHR reuqests rather than WebSockets.

Am I missing something obvious?

In my console I see, in my Networks tab I see no WebSocket, just XHR requests to socket.io:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=lVFuwHcH-XPm8zHhAAAA' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Server Code:

```
var app         = express(),
    http        = require('http').Server(app),
    io          = require('socket.io')(http),

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if(nt == ""){
            socket.emit("message", {"data": "<strong>Waiting for data...</strong>"});
        }else{
            socket.emit("data", {
                "mediumLoadTime": nt.mediumPageLoad(),
                "firstLoadTime": nt.times[0],
                "lastLoadTime": nt.times[nt.times.length-1],
                //"times": nt.times,
                "requests": nt.reqMade.toString(),
                "success": nt.successful.toString(),
                "error": nt.error.toString(),
                "virtualusers": nt.virtualUsers.toString(),
                "host": nt.options.host.toString(),
            });
        }
    }, 10);

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

Client:

```
var socket = io();


   socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
   });
```

In my view I require `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>`

Comment: Can you show example of what you're seeing in your network tab?  Socket.IO uses XHR requests to set things up, and will later switch to WebSockets.

Comment: Are you looking in the WebSockets sub-tab on the network tab?  In Chrome, after selecting the Network tab, you have to then select WebSockets, then click on the request in the the left frame, then click on the Frames tab in the right frame and then you will see actual webSocket requests.  It doesn't update realtime so you have to click on the request again in the left pane to get the right pane to update.  In this manner, you can see the actual WebSocket packets.

Comment: Updated post to reflect these questions! Thanks.